# Pair two arrays with different lenghts

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I m wondering how to implement such situation: I have 2 arrays of strings, lets say one is:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Fiat"];
```

second one is:

```
var colour = ["red", "blue", "green"];
```

And I want to make a loop where for example for 7 interations loop chooses 7 pairs from both arrays like this:

```
   1st iteration "Saab" "red", 
   2nd iteration "Volvo" "blue", 
   3th iteration "BMW" "green", 
   4th iteration "Mercedes" "red", 
   5th iteration "Fiat" "blue", 
   6th iteration "Saab" "green", 
   7th iterathion "Volvo" "red"
```

So it matches first array to second, if array doesn't have values it starts from beginning.

Comment: And what is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count and take the advantage of the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) with the length of the actual array.

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Fiat"],
    colour = ["red", "blue", "green"],
    i,
    length = 7;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(i + 1, cars[i % cars.length], colour[i % colour.length]);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate `cars` with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and use the [`%` operator (remainder)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) on the index (`i`) to get the matching colour:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Mercedes", "Fiat"];
var colour = ["red", "blue", "green"];

var result = cars.map(function(car, i) {
  return [car, colour[i % colour.length]]; // convert to whatever result you need
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The only issue with this answer is that it doesn't output 7 results as requested in the question (But it's still very good approach)